# Condition under which the Clarke's subdifferential is locally Lipschitzian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

Given a locally Lipschitz continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and closed set $$\Omega =\left\lbrace x \in\mathbb{R}^n \ |\  f(x) \leq 0 \right\rbrace$$ such that f is semi-analytic function and analytic inside $\mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus\Omega$ and $\text{Int }{\Omega}$. The Clarke's subdifferential set is the set given by
$$ 
\partial f (x) = {\text{cl co}}\left\lbrace \lim_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \nabla f (x^{k}) \ |\  \text{whenever }  x^{k} \rightarrow x^{*} \text{ and } \lim_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \nabla f (x^{k}) \text{ exist} \right\rbrace
$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n.$ My question is about the context in which this multivalued function satisfies a weak notion of locally Lipschitz continuity for multifunctions; by that I mean that for all convex compact set $K$ there exist a $L>0$ such that for all $x\in K$ there exist a $\delta > 0 $ such that for all $y,z \in B(x,\delta) \cap K $ it holds
$$
d(\partial f (y), \partial f (z)) = \inf_{g\in \partial f (y)} \inf_{g' \in \partial f (z) } \|g - g'\| < L \|y-z\|. 
$$ Note that when the function is locally Fréchet differentiable on an open set containing $\Omega$ with continuous second derivative, this is true. It seems to be true for all functions sufficiently regular. It might be true for piecewise smooth functions with sufficiently regular set of discontinuity of the derivative.

> Is there a good context in which this is true?

Comment: You can suppose that $f$ is smooth, if it helps to get rid of the smoothness of f and just having to worry about the boundary of $\Omega.$ "Usually", its not true: the convex function $f(x) = \sqrt{x^3}$ does not satisfy this.

Comment: Can you clarify a couple of points? What does $\mathrm{cl} \, \mathrm{co}$ refer to? What role does $\Omega$ play - it seems like you could just consider the question on an open domain $U \subset \mathbf{R}^n$?

Comment: $\text{cl co}$ is the closure of the convex hull of a set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull#Definitions. Since the convex hull of a compact set is, again, compact, the closure can be omitted.

Comment: I have strengthened the hypotheses on $f$ and on $\Omega$ now

Comment: It looks that the paper called Lipschitz properties of semi-analytic sets by Adam Parusinski might help with my question. If someone is fluent in algebraic geometry, then it might help with my question. I bet it is an interesting paper. =)

Comment: With the nomenclature of the paper, my function $f$ is  strongly semi-analytic.

Comment: I couldn't follow everything you ask in your question, but I get the feeling that you get Lipschitz continuity for example in the following (relatively nice) scenario. Say the domain of definition of $f$ can be divided into a union of disjoint open sets $U_1,\dots,U_N$ in the sense that $\cup_i \bar{U}_i$ covers the domain. If the restriction of $D f$ to each $U_i$ is Lipschitz with constant $L$ then so is $\partial f$ on their union. Would that answer your question? If so, I'd be happy to write this up: the details don't seem particularly tricky.

Comment: You have asked if that answer my question and It looks so. As far as I can think, that almost the best answer I could get. If you could argue why this is close to the "best-case scenario" I would be grateful. I'm trying to extract the best of my function f, but that does not seem going good up to now, unfortunately